# How to scrape a page generated with a script in C#?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Simple example: Google search page.

http://www.google.com/search?q=foobar

When I get the source of the page, I get the underlying JavaScript. I want the resulting page. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it *looks* as if it is only javascript it really is the full HTML, you can easily confirm with [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=foobar");
string html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"); //returns 85 nodes
```

Comment: How do I access the HTML? The `html` variable contains the script.

Comment: @Igor: look for the `<body>` tag - the HTML content starts afterwards